# Para que serve o secret no express-session?

Tags: node.js, session, express.js

Tenho uma aplicação em express, porém não sei qual a importância de configurar a secret no middleware `session()`.

Alguém poderia me explicar o que a secret faz? qual é a função?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, você deve ter isso. Um secret de sessão no connect é simplesmente usado para calcular o hash. Sem a string, o acesso à sessão seria "negado". Dê uma olhada nos  [documentos de conexão](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html), que devem ajudar um pouco.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, valeu!

Comment: Amigo, você sabe alguma coisa sobre dependências do ionic? Tenho uma questão em aberto, mas ninguém me respondeu ainda.

Link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/405856/problema-de-depend%c3%aancia-ionic-x-firebase

Comment: Vou lá dar uma olhada